# Will Time Machine work effectively with a WD MyCloud NAS device?

Tags: time-machine, nas

I recently purchased a Western Digital MyCloud NAS device. I'm wondering if there would be a problem with using it for backups with Time Machine on a Mac mini (late 2012) running OS X 10.9.5. Is there anything I should know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I read there should not be any problems.

> By default, the server comes with three public share folders called
>   Public, SmartWare, and **Time Machine Backup**. As the names suggest,
>   the Public folder is for storing public data, and the other two are
>   for backups of Windows and Mac machines, respectively.
>
> As soon as the device is plugged in, all of these public folders are
>   available to all connected devices in the home network. From a Windows
>   computer, you can browse for these share folders and copy data (such
>   as digital content) over. **Macs will immediately see the My Cloud as
>   an available destination for Time Machine backup and the My Cloud will
>   also appear on Finder**. All DLNA-enabled network media player
>   devices, such as the WD TV , will also immediately find the content
>   stored on the My Cloud for streaming purposes.

<sub>Source: http://www.cnet.com/products/wd-my-cloud-2-tb/</sub>

Here are some [instructions how to set it up](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3561/~/using-a-wd-network-drive-with-apple-time-machine-backups).

Comment: Thank you, Buscar, I'll research the links you provided.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issues as Evert. I have now given up and pulled the plug on my WD My Cloud. Although I have seen that some people are getting on okay with it, most of what I have read concurs with my own finding. It is no good as a time machine back up. It is terribly slow. My last successful back up, which added approx 250gb to my already backed up 1.25tb took 7 days. Prior to the verification messages now encountered I would wait a day or two to get passed the 'Preparing data' message. I can no longer even access the wd my drive as a timemachine and it no longer recognises the info, even though the amount of space on the WD cloud drive indicates the backed up info is still on there.
I am converting back to a usb external hard drive.
I would recommend buying anything rather than the WD MyCloud if using it with a MAC.

Answer (score 1):

I've had very negative experiences with it. It works for a while, but then Time machine will always complain that verification failed and has to re-create the entire backup from scratch *every time*. There appear to be others with the same issues as well, so I would *not* recommend this for Time Machine. Very possible that the issue is on Apple's end though.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it keeps on crashing my backups, and I have to delete them so often, that I would advise NOT to buy one....

Answer (score 0):

I searched for evaluations like this before purchasing, but not searchingly enough, I guess.

## Pros

Western Digital's own syncing and backup to the NAS software is pretty cool so far.

## Con

After purchasing in January, 2016 with the latest software updates, I experienced glacial Time Machine performance with hours and hours spent preparing backups. Then when I got a full Time Machine backup, Time Machine refused to recognize the Time Machine share on the NAS.

Buyer beware!